# Confused permissions on mkdir() call

Tags: php, permissions, mkdir

The question itself it quite simple, but it's really driving me crazy... I've read many other questions on Stack, but no matter how I change the code, the problem keeps occurring...

Why does...

```
if(!is_dir($dir)){
    clearstatcache();
    $mask = umask(0);
    if(mkdir($dir, 6750)) chmod($dir, 6750);
    umask($mask);
}
```

... produces...

```
d--s-wxrwT 2 owner group 4096 Jan 27 20:22 dir/
```

... when `$dir` is the absolute path to the newly created `dir/` ?

As you can see, even though I request a 6750 permissions set, I get a lovely, yet useless, 5136... (the user and group, however, are correct) Here's what I've done :

- Clearing the stat cache.
- Setting the PHP umask to 0 before creating, and restoring it right after.
- Chmod the newly created folder on success, just to be sure.

And here's what I know :

- The system's umask value is 0037, which isn't the difference between 6750 and 5136.
- The user creating the folder (www-data) has the same umask, and owns the parent directory with write permissions.
- I can log as www-data on a terminal, and execute `chmod 6750` succesfully, getting proper results.

Any reason why it seems like PHP forgot how to calculate ? Some questions mentionned an additional Apache2 parameters messing around, yet I cannot figure out which one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wont it be simpler without `chmod($dir, 6750)`?

```
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($path, 06750); 
umask($old);
```

And one more thing your mode value should start from 0.
Read [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) about mode possible values.

Comment: `chmod` is a idiot thing. I don't protest on this, I was just kind of desperate... Adding a zero fixed it, thank you. I also removed all useless lines. I just thought the zero was the usual part of UNIX permissions (sticky bit, GUID, UUID, ...). I guess this is just another PHP surprise...

Comment: I am very glad that I helped you.